# How do I detect if an actionSheet was dismissed?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I display an actionSheet in SwiftUI like this

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $actionSheetControl.showActionSheet) { () -> ActionSheet in
  getActionSheetPurchase(item)
}
```

This can be dismissed by tapping outside the action sheet.

How can I detect if the action sheet is dismissed in a case like that?

Comment: You can use `onChange()` modifier for that. Read this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.onChange` for action sheet presented state like on demo below

```
    @Binding var showActionSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {

       // some view here
        .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
              // some ActionSheet here
        }
        .onChange(of: showActionSheet) { flag in
            if !flag {
                print("dismissed")        // << here !!
            }
        }
    }
```